# MySQL use select query result in another query with logical OR

Tags: mysql

Need some help to construct this query.

```
Q1 = select fruits from tableA;
```

Result: apple, banana, orange

```
Q2 = select * from tableB where (fruitname = 'apple' OR fruitname = 'banana' OR fruitname = 'orange');
```

How can I combine both the above queries into a single query?
And is it efficient to run a combined query versus 2 individual queries.

The script is written in PHP.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from tableB where fruitname IN (select fruits from tableA)
```

for efficency, try for Yourself = )

Comment: I found this one simple for my slow grey cells ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use a JOIN for a more efficient result:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM tableB b
JOIN tableA a
ON b.fruitname = a.fruits
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from tableB where fruitname IN (select fruits from tableA);
```